# WPF: Accessing Journal history of Frame by external button controls

Tags: binding

I am wondering if there is an easy way to use back and forward navigation of the frame journal but using buttons that are not part of the frame.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the frame set `ShowsNavigationUI` to false, then create something that looks like:

```
<Button Content="Back" 
        Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" 
        IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding CanGoBack}" />
<Button Content="Next" 
        Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseForward}" 
        IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding CanGoForward}" />
```

And then use the appropriate events.